# Evaluate SQL where clause in c# without SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a large set of conditions (I don't know them ahead of time) that I need count against a relatively small SQL Server table (< 10,000 rows). Each condition is in the form of a SQL where clause. Currently, I build a complete sql statement in the form of "select count(*) from some_table where " + Where_Clause; and I let SQL Server return the count to me. I do this in a loop to get all the counts I need for all the various conditions.

I'm looking for ways to speed this up when I have dozens or hundreds of counts I need to run. I don't know the statements ahead of time. Some will select the whole table, some may not select any rows. I've tried the following solutions:

1. Issuing the queries in parallel - saw minimal improvement even when not doing any locking
2. Writing them as complex counts on case statements so I can run multiple where clauses in one statement
3. Passing many queries together as UNIONs and getting the results back as one result set

None of these options have had a fantastic improvement in runtime (sometimes it would run more slowly) and with the added complexity, I don't feel any of them are worth it.

My question is: I can very quickly load the entire table into a DataTable object just by running one "select *" against it. If I had the whole table in memory, is there a way to run counts against it without going back and forth to SQL Server? I'm hoping to cut out the overhead of the: network, I/O, locking, etc.

The most complex where clause would be something like:

```
a=1 or b in (2,3) or c<4 or d like '%5' or substring(e,2,1)='z'
```

So it's not trivial and supporting as much as possible of T-SQL would be ideal, but I don't think DataTable's .Select() method supports this OR is it very fast. So given a table of data in memory, can I could rows using T-SQL syntax very fast (or in parallel)?

Comment: You might look into Dynamic Linq to see if it performs any better...http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx.  If the list of filter criteria is known you might also be able to use PredicateBuilder...http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: is there a set number of predefined where clauses? or are they composited at the user's request?

Comment: The user creates them using another tool. Each query has a name too so when generating reports, they want to know how many rows match each set of criteria and put a name on it too. So they'll get reports that say: "good: 100, bad: 50, red: 25, yellow: 100..." etc. Arbitrarily many queries with whatever criteria they've designed, but all against a single small table which is why I want to load the table once and run them all in memory.

Comment: One thing you could try is using a database system that stores your database in memory instead of on persistent storage. I used MonetDB for a class once and though it was way overkill for what we were doing with it, its performance is pretty awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into using LINQ to SQL, or possibly building the queries as Stored Procedures that you can execute.

Answer (score 0):

Things to try

a) Make sure you've got the right indexes - check the query plan for the most complex query, and make sure there are no table scans in there.

b) Do multiple queries in the same request using something like this.

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Foo; SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Bar", con))
var ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
var ds = new DataSet();
ad.Fill(ds);

var foo = ds.Tables[0];
var bar = ds.Tables[1];
```

Comment: There are too many columns to index and I don't know ahead of time which ones would need them anyway. You're suggestion about multiple queries in statement is about what I did in idea #3 in my post - except I had only one statement. Surprisingly running 100 statements union'd together wasn't any faster than running 100 individual queries.

Comment: Hmm. That implies that it's the queries themselves that are taking the time, not the round trip to the server. Without better indexing, there's not a lot that I can think of. Maybe try and normalise the data into separate tables, rather than one large one?